# Unable to start KODI / XBMC from the dash in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ati, xbmc

I installed KOBI / XBMC using the below steps and it completed successfully.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

*But* I am unable to find it by searching in the dash either by name (`xbmc` or `kobi`, but if I type `kobi` in a terminal it opens up and runs fine!

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just a comment, but it's `kodi ` with a `d`. And not `kobi` with a `b`.

Comment: According to the wiki, it's `kodi ... for 14.0 and up` and `xbmc ... for 13.2` - [HOW-TO:Install Kodi for Linux - Kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/Installing_XBMC_for_Linux#Ubuntu)

Comment: I remember experiencing this once ages ago with XBMC. Ubuntu needs to be restarted. XBMC/Kodi, installes allot of files, system and such. So, when installed it needs a reboot to load everything. Thats why the `.desktop` for kodi hasn't been loaded. Needs a reboot.

Comment: Sorry for wrong spelling's above, did a restart and still the same prob, hence posted the issue :(

Comment: purge it like so: `sudo apt-get purge xbmc kodi` remove dependencies: `sudo apt-get autoremove`, and reinstall: `sudo apt-get install kodi`. Due note that this might just be a bug with the new release. Developers forgot to make the `.desktop` file? :P

Comment: great, will try a reinstall and update, waiting for other downloads to finish :)

Comment: Great, seems to have worked, uninstalled, reinstalled reboot and everything up fine and running, thank you - blade19899 .... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due note that this might just be a bug with the new release. Maybe the developers forgot to make the `.desktop` file? :P

Purge it like so:

```
sudo apt-get purge xbmc kodi
```

Remove dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install kodi
```